# Can't upgrade ovirt on the system and gui level

Tags: ovirt

I have tried to update oVirt nodes through GUI but I have failed with no error message.

So then after setting maintenance and draining the host I have run the upgrade oVirt to latest version with dnf/yum directly though ssh but I am getting the following error...

```
 ~# dnf upgrade
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:13 ago on Wed 08 Sep 2021 12:03:06 PM CEST.
Error:
 Problem 1: cannot install the best update candidate for package ovirt-host-dependencies-4.4.7-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides python3-os-brick needed by ovirt-host-dependencies-4.4.8-1.el8.x86_64
 Problem 2: package ovirt-host-4.4.8-1.el8.x86_64 requires ovirt-host-dependencies = 4.4.8-1.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package ovirt-host-4.4.7-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides python3-os-brick needed by ovirt-host-dependencies-4.4.8-1.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run following command and rerun dnf upgrade again

```
yum update ovirt-release44 -y
```

Credit > https://www.mail-archive.com/users@ovirt.org/msg67508.html